# How to emulate a pcie device which has a cpu?

Tags: linux, qemu, pci-e

Now, some pcie device has a cpu, ex:DPU.

I want to use qemu to emulate this device.

Can qemu support this requirment？

Comment: qemu is open source, so just roll some of your own code and volia it will support this device

Answer (score 2):

QEMU's emulation framework doesn't support having devices which have fully programmable CPUs which can execute arbitrary guest-provided code in the same way as the main system emulated CPUs. (The main blocker is that all the CPUs in the system have to be the same architecture, eg all x86 or all Arm.)

For devices that have a CPU on them as part of their implementation but where that CPU is generally running fixed firmware that exposes a more limited interface to guest code, a QEMU device model can provide direct emulation of that limited interface, which is typically more efficient anyway.

In theory you could write a device that did a purely interpreted emulation of an onboard CPU, using QEMU facilities like timers and bottom-half callbacks to  interpret a small chunk of instructions every so often. I don't know of any examples of anybody having written a device like that, though. It would be quite a lot of work and the speed of the resulting emulation would not be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by hoisting two instances of QEMU, one built with the host system architecture and the other with the secondary architecture, and connecting them through some interface.

This has been done by Xilinx by starting two separate QEMU processes with some inter-process communication between them, and by Neuroblade by building QEMU in nios2 architecture as a shared library and then loading it from a QEMU process that models the host architecture (in this case the interface can simply be modelled by direct function calls).

Related:

- [How can I use QEMU to simulate mixed platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229262/how-can-i-use-qemu-to-simulate-mixed-platforms)
- https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2021-12/msg01969.html